# Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon - Hibernate doesn't save data

Tags: linux, multi-boot, linux-mint, hibernate, swap

I recently dual-booted my Windows 10 machine with Linux Mint 19. When I realized that I couldn't hibernate my PC to switch into Windows without losing all my open windows, I did a quick Google search and followed [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=273202) tutorial. After doing so, I do have a hibernate button in the power menu, and the `sudo systemctl hibernate` command does work, but once I do hibernate, and boot back into Linux Mint, none of my windows were saved, and it's as if my PC had just shutdown normally.

---

```
apixel@apixel:~$ sudo swapon --show

NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  16G   0B   -2
```

---

```
apixel@apixel:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           786M  1.4M  784M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   73G   37G   33G  53% /
tmpfs           3.9G  5.9M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   55M   42M  57% /boot/efi
tmpfs           786M   24K  786M   1% /run/user/1000
```

---

Screenshot of System Monitor: https://gyazo.com/4536b46724eecb41149c8e1734c4acf2

---

Specs:
PC: Acer Swift 3
OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon
Cinnamon Version: 4.0.10
Linux Kernel: 4.15.0-47-generic
Processor: Intel Core i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz x 4
Memory: 7.7 GiB
Hard Drives: 76.5 GB

---

How can I get hibernate to work as I'd expect, coming from Windows?